# Pandas Read Excel Sheet as csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save one sheet of an excel document as a csv file and run it in colab using pandas.  I saved the sheet as a csv and uploaded it to github....but when I run this code I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
naep = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngpsu22/NAEP-Data/master/naep_race.csv')
```

Error: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encountered with similar issue in the past, specifying the encoding during csv reading came to rescue with reference of few google searches:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='ISO-8859–1')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='latin1')
```

[unicodedecodeerror](https://www.edureka.co/community/66416/unicodedecodeerror-codec-decode-position-invalid-start-byte)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of solution]

You can specify <encoding = 'unicode_escape'> while reading csv, As you can see in screenshot